# Download and upload files and folders between GCS and Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, download, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-storage

I have some files and folders on **GCS(Google Cloud Storage)**:

[image]

And I have some files and folders on **Cloud Shell** as well:

[image]

Now, I want to download and upload these files and folders between **GCS** and **Cloud Shell**:

Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: What about using gsutil from the Cloud Shell command line?  Perhaps the gsutil cp command?

Comment: OK, I'll try that. It's actually "copy" rather than "download". I see.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's your use case?

Comment: "Why I want to do this" is to delete too many unnecessary files on GCS at once at the same time using ".txt" file that lists unnecessary files on Cloud Shell. I'm going to put the ".txt" file on GCS, then, when I want to delete unnecessary files, I'm going to download the ".txt" file from GCS to Cloud Shell, then, delete them with the ".txt" file running some command.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the objects from the buckets in the Cloud Storage using `gsutil cp` command in the cloud shell:

```
gsutil cp gs://BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME SAVE_TO_LOCATION
```

Also, you can download the files using the console by clicking on the **Download** icon associated with the object and upload it to the cloud shell.

For more information, refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#gsutil).

Answer (score 0):

##### --- Download files and folders from GCS to Cloud Shell ---

Hint:

```
gsutil cp gs://<GCS_Bucket_Name>/<File_Name> <Cloud_Shell_Directory>
```

This downloads **"one file"** on **GCS** to current directory on **Cloud Shell**:

```
gsutil cp gs://test.com/file1.json .
```

This downloads **"two files"** on **GCS** to current directory on **Cloud Shell**:

```
gsutil cp gs://test.com/file1.json gs://test.com/file2.txt .
```

This downloads **"one file"** and **"one folder"** on **GCS** to current directory on **Cloud Shell**:

```
(Hint-1: "-r" is needed to download folders)
(Hint-2: If a folder is empty, the folder is not downloaded)

gsutil cp -r gs://test.com/file1.json gs://test.com/folder1 .
```

##### --- Upload files and folders from Cloud Shell to GCS: ---

Hint:

```
gsutil cp <Cloud_Shell_File> gs://<GCS_Bucket_Name>
```

This uploads **"one file"** on **Cloud Shell** to **GCS**:

```
gsutil cp file1.json gs://test.com
```

This uploads **"two files"** on **Cloud Shell** to **GCS**:

```
gsutil cp file1.json file2.txt gs://test.com
```

This uploads **"one file"** and **"one folder"** on **Cloud Shell** to **GCS**:

```
(Hint-1: "-r" is needed to upload folders)
(Hint-2: If a folder is empty, the folder is not uploaded)

gsutil cp -r file1.json folder1 gs://test.com
```